Vuetify3: Emitting Input Events to parent component
{
    "type": "form",
    "id": 240808,
    "title": "Some App",
    "steps": [
      { 
          "type": "stepOne",
          "id": 1,
          "title": "Personal Details", 
          "fields": [
              {
                  "type": "text",
                  "id": "1002",
                  "label": "First Name",
                  "model": "firstName",
                  "value": "",
                  "hint": "",
                  "persistentHint": false,
                  "required": true
              },
              {
                  "type": "text",
                  "id": "1003",
                  "label": "Last Name",
                  "model": "lastName",
                  "value": "",
                  "hint": "",
                  "persistentHint": false,
                  "required": true
              },
...

I have some data.json from which I initialize a formValues object in the data() function of the parent component to loop through the fields to create a v-text-field for each field obj.
Here is the parent component, where the currentStep and steps are just conditions upon which specific data field should be rendered.
data() {
        return {
            currentStep: 1,
            steps: formData.steps,
            formData,
            formValues: this.initializeFormValues(formData);
        };
    },
 computed: {
        currentStepData() {
            return this.formData.steps.find(step => step.id === this.currentStep) || { fields: [] };
        }
    },
methods: {
        initializeFormValues() {
            const formValues = {};
            formData.steps.forEach(step => {
                if (step.fields && Array.isArray(step.fields)) {
                    step.fields.forEach(field => {
                        formValues[field.model] = field.value || '';
                    });
                }
            });
            return formValues;
        }

Template of parent component, with the v-model coming from initialized formValues object
                    <v-form>
                        <div v-for="(field, index) in currentStepData.fields" :key="index">
                            <text-field :fieldData="field" v-model:value="formValues[field.model]"></text-field>
                        </div>
                    </v-form>

The v-text-field child component should emit the inputted value:
<template>
    <v-col>
        <v-text-field :value="modelValue || ''" :type="fieldData.type || 'text'" :id="fieldData.model || ''"
            :name="fieldData.model || ''" :label="fieldData.label || ''"
            @input="handleInput"></v-text-field>
    </v-col>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'TextField',
    props: {
        fieldData: Object,
        modelValue: String
    },
    emits: ['update:modelValue'],
    methods: {
        handleInput(event) {
            console.log('Logged event:' event);
            const value = event.target.value;
            console.log(`Emitting value: ${value}`); // Log emitted value
            this.$emit('update:modelValue', value);  // Emit the event
        }

    }
}
</script>

Here is console log when I type a "t":
InputEvent {isTrusted: true, _vts: 1724755177671, data: 't', isComposing: false, inputType: 'insertText', …}
TextField.vue:28 Emitting value:
The emitted value is "".
I tested emitting values from child to parent component without vuetify 3 and that works just fine.
<template>
    <div>
        <label>{{ fieldData.label }}</label>
        <input type="text" :value="modelValue"
            @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)" />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'TextField',
    props: {
        fieldData: Object,
        modelValue: String
    },
    emits: ['update:modelValue']
};
</script>


You tagged this as Vue/Vuetify 3, but the code is v2, according to the :value and @input on the VTextField. Please check which version you are using, and update props/events accordingly (i.e. :modelValue/@update:modelValue) if you indeed use v3.

@MoritzRingler
"vue": "^3.4.31",
"vuetify": "^3.6.11"
I'm using the options API with vue3. I dont see how the code is v2 tbh, could be wrong. Maybe just tell me how to emit child input value in vuetify3.

In v3, ':value' has to be :modelValue and '@inputhas to be@update:modelValue. This is a breaking change in v-model` in Vue 3 (see migration guilde), not just Vuetify, but you can also find it in the VTextField docs.
